# Why is 'static lifetime required for values valid past thread.join()?

Tags: rust

I understand why 'static is required of references passed to a thread *if* that thread is 'detached' meaning theres no way to tell when the spawned thread finishes execution. However, if we keep a join handle for the spawned thread, I would think the compiler would be able to reason that the lifetime of the spawned thread would be that of the join handle? And further that it would be valid to pass references<'a> to a thread with handle<'b> where 'a outlives 'b. What am I missing? Why doesn't the rust compiler do this?

```
fn main() {
  let foo = Foo::new();
  let my_ref = &foo;
            
  // Error: my_ref needs a 'static lifetime to be moved into a thread
  let thread = std::thread::spawn(move || test(my_ref));
  thread.join();
            
  // if foo isn't dropped until here, wouldn't its lifetime out live the thread? 
  // Why would the lifetime be required to be static?
}
```

Comment: Because the compiler doesn't do any special analysis for threads. Fortunately, _we_ can design an API that lets the compiler know that, and [such API was indeed designed](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html).

Comment: Why? Many reasons. For one, this would have to be special-cased by the compiler which would make it inconsistent with similar code. Two, this isn't really composable since returning the handle wouldn't be able to offer the same behavior (the compiler does function-local analysis only for borrow-checking). Thirdly, something may return or panic between the spawn and join which would make any guarantee much less likely to be enforceable. Lastly, we have `std::thread::scope` for that.